# Insert data from html form using PHP and PostgresSQL does not work, just produces a view of local process.php

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am following the following tutorial: https://www.studentstutorial.com/php-postgreysql/insert.

I am using pgAdmin, followed the code closely, modified credentials to my database, and was able to replicate the HTML page. Yet, when I fill out the form, and submit, the page takes me to the local path of the process.php file. Nothing appears in my database, and no errors are produced. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the local path of process.php"? Precisely what path is shown in the browser address bar at that time? And what exactly do you see in the main browser window? Do you see php code on the screen? Did you install php and also run your html form via the local webserver (i.e. `http://localhost/...etc`)?

Comment: When running the file straight from the working directory it will run once I hit the submit button but the php code will show on the screen and nothing is changed in the database. I was able to install the php package in the terminal and run the local webserver to check the script. When I do that I receive an error saying "This page isn't working if the problem continues, contact the site owner HTTP ERROR 405". When I open up the console log to investigate further I get the error "(index):6773 c
 "(index):6773 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated". How should I proceed?

Comment: You definitely can't run it directly from  your working directory. That will never invoke a http server or the php interpreter to run the code. How exactly did you run it via the local webserver then? Do you already have apache or something installed? Or did you use php's built in test server? What address did you put in the browser bar to reach the html page? What address then shows when you then submit the form? The 405 error makes me suspicious you're still not loading it properly via the webserver

Comment: P.s. I think the last message you mentioned is some internal Chrome debug notice, you can ignore it